# Attempting to use puppet 5 client against puppet 6 server - ssl error

Tags: ssl, puppet

I have a bunch of ARM based boxes that are stuck on puppet client v5. I've recently updated the server installation to v6 though. V6 clients are working ok.

When I attempt to pair a v5 client with the new server install I'm seeing this error:

> Error: Could not request certificate: request https://v6server.org:8140//puppet-ca/v1/certificate_revocation_list/ca failed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed: [unable to get issuer certificate for /CN=Puppet CA: v6server.org]

(Note the extra "/" after the port #. If I **curl** against the corrected URL (without the extra "/") I get the expected cert(s).

I've been digging through the puppet client ruby code to (so far) no avail.

Wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue.

Comment: The cipher algorithm may have changed between major versions. I would be skeptical about that if it was using the JRuby OpenSSL gem, because that thing is kind of long dead, but I believe it uses the MRI gem for this. Regardless, I think you already know you are probably not going to be able to workaround this issue you are facing without an agent upgrade.

Comment: Ugh. I really, truly hope there is a way around this. If I make the call without the extra '/' it works.. but finding that bug is proving to be tough indeed.

Comment: You could consider [filing a ticket](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa).  Puppet ordinarily promises that previous-version clients work with new-version masters.  I don't think they've done differently with P6, so this definitely looks like a bug to me.  And I think you could justify requesting high priority for it, since you're totally blocked, though they might consider the option of switching to P6 clients to be a viable workaround.

Comment: Alternatively, if indeed you can get the certs via `curl` then there is a fair chance that you could install them manually, but I couldn't tell you exactly how.